# DRF - Giving feedback to developer regarding bad inputs using django-filters

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm developing a REST API with django rest framework but I'm not finding a way of validating the inputs from the request with django-filters.

For example, say I have the model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Time it was created")
    is_important = models.BooleanField(help_text="If the event is important")
```

And I have the filter:

```
class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    important = filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_important')
    since = filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(name='timestamp', lookup_type='gt')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

If, in my request, I insert a bad date like **{url}/?since=2016-02-31T00:00Z** or **{url}/?since=yesterday**, instead of receiving feedback about what is wrong with the request, the API will just returns a list without any results. This doesn't indicate that the developer made a bad request, it could just mean that there are no events under those terms.

The inverse happens with booleans, if in my request I send **{url}/?is_important=maybe**, it will return all the results without any filtering.

So, my question is: Does DRF have a way of validating these kind of inputs and return a meaningful response to the developer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-filter has a [`strict`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filterset.html#strict) attribute which controls the handling of validation errors.

```py
import django_filters as filters
from django_filters.filterset import STRICTNESS

class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    important = filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_important')
    since = filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(name='timestamp', lookup_type='gt')

    strict = STRICTNESS.RAISE_VALIDATION_ERROR

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django_filters.filterset import STRICTNESS
```

Above import will results to ImportError: cannot import name 'STRICTNESS'

This is because STRICTNESS was moved: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migration.html#filterset-strictness-handling-moved-to-view-788

There is no official documentation yet but I was able to trigger/raise the error by override of FilterBackend from the comment 
https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/788#issuecomment-409635087

```
class StrictDjangoFilterBackend(django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend):
    """Return no results if the query doesn't validate."""

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        try:
            return super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view):
        except serializers.ValidationError:
            return queryset.none()
```

sample working api call on my datetimefield (time has to be present):

```
GET /api/xxxx?start_date=2015-01-01T0:0:00Z
```